# get_template_directory_uri() inside a php var that stores html

Tags: php, wordpress

I am sorry, this might be a simple question, but I've tried searching around and can't seem to find what is wrong with this next function. I have a php var that stores html but I want to put `get_template_directory_uri();` inside of it.

```
// Add Hamburger Icon as Last Item
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 10, 2 );

function add_search_to_nav( $items, $args )
 $items .= '<li class="hamburger"><a href="#"><img src=" ' . get_template_directory_uri()."/assets/images/menu-burger.svg" . ' "</a></li>';
 return $items;
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? What doesn't work?

Comment: @cale_b I get a blank screen in wordpress. The issue is with `.=`

Comment: I don't think that line is the problem, at least the way you have it.  You might try it this way, which is slightly simpler: `$items .= '<li class="hamburger"><a href="#"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '"/assets/images/menu-burger.svg"></a></li>';` - additionally, turn on WP_DEBUG (in your wp-config file), so you can SEE the error, instead of getting the white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `{` for your `add_search_to_nav` function. Your `img` tag was also missing `>` and there should be no spaces before and after link in `href` of `a`.
You can also remove `$args` from `add_search_to_nav` parameters and `2` from parameters of `add_filter` since you're not using `$args` anyway.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_to_nav', 10);

function add_search_to_nav($items)
{
    $items .= '<li class="hamburger"><a href="#"><img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/menu-burger.svg' . '"/></a></li>';
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Igor for your solution and explanation. Have a nice day!